# Best way to pass a lot of variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, url, session-variables

I was using a URL to save/pass the variables and I ran into a problem because the URL was too long.

I believe Sessions won't work because the user will be clicking on a link in their email to view a page that uses all the variables.

I realize I could use MySQL to save the variables for each user, but I was wondering if there are other solutions that allow passing of a lot of variables that might work as well as or better than using a database?

Comment: based on the very small amount of information provided, i would suggest a db

Comment: Is there some additional information you need to know that might change your suggestion? I thought I gave all pertinent details.

Comment: Why a down vote? What is wrong with my question?

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity.

Comment: no information on the source of the variables, there use, why the email ... we have nothing more than the very little you typed to go on

Comment: The source of the variables is a form. 

There are 366 check boxes and 30 textarea boxes for comments. 

The email is sent once the form is completed to alert our client that they can now view the results based on what was checked. 

I could create a database, although many times only 2 or 3 boxes will be checked with perhaps 1 or 2 comments, so most of the time the URL would work, but it could get too long if a lot of options are checked or the comments are long.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I avoid using GET parameters ( url string ) to pass any information because I like clean user experience.

POST is much more preferable but slower option.

To answer your question, usually an email link contains a userid which is then checked against the database and all the other information pulled out based on that one id. If this is part of an email campaign there's the second variable you can tack on. If you're tackling 20, 30, 40 url parameters that's not the best approach.

Use session to keep user id around based on cookies saved on the client ( browser ) then on the server you can access any additional information you may need for that specific page load.

I strongly urge you to keep your session size to a minimum for each user as when you scale up that will prove detrimental to your system's long term health.